# Issue with the Halting Problem

Tags: halting-problem

***For clarity, I'll claim the supposed impossible program to be 'Code X'.***

Something doesn't seem to make sense about the proof against Code X:

Consider a code that halts if you input oranges, but doesn't if you input apples. The answer to whether it halts is in this very obvious case is that 'it depends'. So either this is a much more simple proof or the Halting problem excludes input-dependant codes (or assumes a pre-determined input). I'll stick with the latter.

How can Code X be inputted into itself if it requires an input (remember that the above analysis tells us that Code X only works for code that's not input dependent)?

And even if you can reason past that, what if Code X requires that the code it's testing needs to be run a (finite) number of times before making its verdict as to whether it halts or not?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You talk about "the supposed impossible program", but I'm not sure what you're referring to.  It seems like some context is missing.  As far as "it depends", that's beside the point.  The halting problem is to determine, given a specific program and a specific input, whether the program will halt when run on that particular input or not.

Answer (score 0):

The proof for the halting problem is as follows:

Let us assume towards contradiction that such 'Code X' exists, we will call it $H$. Notice that $H$ is a program, and we can write down its code. Basically, its just a piece of text - unless we give it meaning.

We want to show that we cant give it meaning, in some meaningful way. Since we assumed that it is the code that solves the halting problem, the "correct" meaning for $H$ is to accept when it receives text that corresponds to some code and an input to that code, and it would halt.

Now, we want to look at another program, $A$ that accepts one input (and not two like $H$ did) and has the following code:

1. get stuck into an infinite loop if $H(X, X)=true$
2. else, halt

where $X$ is the said input. Consider $A(text(A))$: We run $A$ on its own code!

If $A$ would halt with this input $X=text(A)$, then we know that $H(text(A),text(A))=false$, but from the definition of $H$ it would mean that $A$ would not halt on $text(A)$! A contradiction. A similar argument can be shown if $H(text(A), text(A))=true$, and from this we know that such program $A$ cannot exist, and therefore also $H$ cannot exist.